# Passing a IS NOT NULL through a sqlparameter

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a query in sql server 2008. That I want to either pass a value from the dropdownlist or IS NOT NULL (so it shows all of the values). What's the best way to handle this? I know you can't pass the string "IS NOT NULL" to the parameter. I'm a bit stuck on this one.

ASP.NET 3.5 and SQL Server 2008.

Comment: You are using it in a stored proc?

Comment: Yes I am using a stored proc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this is a stored procedure, say your parameter is called `@Param1`, have the parameter set to `NULL` to indicate `IS NOT NULL`, as follows:

```
SELECT ...
FROM   ...
WHERE  (
           (@Param1 IS NULL AND field1 IS NOT NULL)
           OR (field1 = @Param1)
       )
```

---

**Suggested by GSerg**

Testing `ISNULL(@Param1, field1) = field1` with the following:

```
DECLARE  @test1 nvarchar(10) = 'testing',
         @test2 nvarchar(10) = NULL; -- or 'random' or 'testing'

SELECT   1
WHERE    ISNULL(@test2, @test1) = @test1;
```

Computations are showing as 1 for each case. This appears to be a better solution than my original answer.

Comment: That's what I said but you said it first and better. +1 to you and -1 answer to me. ;-)

Comment: ... which can be simplified to `where isnull(@param, field1) = field1`.

Comment: Thanks Chris :) You don't deserve a -1. No-one does (that's my philosophy on S.O.)

Comment: @GSerg: Nice simplification. I would check first on the execution plan that when `@param` is `NULL`, the computation for comparing the column is skipped (I have a feeling it isn't).

Comment: ... Seems it is skipped. The Actual Execution plan only performs 1 computation in the three possible scenarios. Nice! (I'll add this to the answer)

Comment: Guys, I appreciate it. I didn't know that you can compare a column name to column name. Actually I don't quite understand it. But cool nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the like operator:

```
select * from table1 where name like @param
```

setting `@param` to `%` if you want not null values. But then you have to escape the `%`.